# Using Powershell as COMSPEC

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, powershell, powershell-2.0, visual-c++-2010

I am trying to setup COMSPEC as powershell as default interpreter. This helps me to handle the situation if the current directory is an UNC for applications being launched using system(..).  We also have thirdparty tools for to support unix utilities under Windows. One of them is ls.exe.  In my testing, I found system("ls -al") was being picked from Powershell instead of the thirdparty directory which is already in PATH. Is there any way I can avoid using powershell alias through an environment variable? Or use a custom alias redirecting to thirdparty directory by an environment variable? Or is there any way to stop using alias from powershell and just use as interpreter by environment variable?

-Karthik

Answer (score 1):

The command `get-item alias:ls` show that the alias `ls` is an item of the drive `alias`. So to remove this item you can use : `Remove-Item alias:ls`.

Now a bit like unix shell you've got the concept of profle file where you can put this command so the it's run prior to any shell execution. More information about profile in [Windows PowerShell owner's manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692764.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I set COMSPEC to powershell and expect system(..), popen(..) ( in C for example ) to use the new interpreter, i was expecting if there is a way to instruct powershell not to use its alias but expect the executable to be picked from PATH env. If there is a way, please let me know. Otherwise the solution that I can think of based on your alias suggestion is to configure in user profile to turn off aliases for ls, mkdir,..... based on an application defined environment variable.